# How to set up DNS for inbound emails using Node.js

Tags: node.js, email, dns, digital-ocean, mx-record

I would like to parse inbound emails in a Node.js app hosted on Digital Ocean. I want to create an email address for my app's domain that can post to a webhook. How do I create an email address like `name@example.com` (or `name@subdomain.example.com`)? I am trying to avoid creating one through a third party because I just need to quickly parse the incoming content, and don't need all the functionality of regular email.

For parsing, I am using Mailin.io, and following Mailin's [documentation](http://mailin.io/doc) I have changed my Domain records on Digital Ocean as follows:

```
MX    10           subdomain.example.com
A     subdomain    [ip address of my droplet]
```

I have the webhook set up at `http://www.example.com/webhook`, and if I post using `curl`, I get the expected response, but I can't figure out how to post to the webhook via email.

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: To receive email for your domain, you will need an SMTP server that is configured as an MX Record in DNS to be the recipient of incoming email for your domain.  That SMTP server can then be configured for what it does with the incoming email which could be something as simple as dumping it into files in a known directory which you can read from node.js or at the other end of the spectrum putting it into a database that an IMAP server might use to allow you to access it. To receive email you need an SMTP server that is configured with an MX record to be the receiver of email for your domain.

Comment: That's why I'm using Mailin.io, which is acting as the SMTP server. I'm not sure how to configure the MX records though.

Comment: Does the MX record point to the IP address of your mailin.io server?

Comment: It points to the server address of my webapp, which is a Digital Ocean droplet. Does it need a separate server?

Comment: It needs to point to whatever server and process is listening for incoming smtp connections.

Comment: Should be the same then, just on a different port.